# "Buffer Error", "Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Tags: java, android, google-maps

### Here is my java code where I am getting this error in google map

```
public String getJSONFromUrl(String url)
{ 

    try {
        Log.e("jsonURL", url);
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        json = sb.toString();
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return json;
}
```

### I am calling this method here

```
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {      
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
```

Please suggest me the way to resolve this issue.

here is the url:  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=30.7019818,76.6836021&destination=31.344452033528295,48.71375273913145&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true&key=*google_api_key*

Here is the logcat

> 10-06 18:54:18.529 17583-18349/com.app.io.taxiapp W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
>   10-06 18:54:18.529 17583-18349/com.app.io.taxiapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
>   10-06 18:54:18.529 17583-18349/com.app.io.taxiapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
>   10-06 18:54:18.529 17583-18349/com.app.io.taxiapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
>   10-06 18:54:18.529 17583-18349/com.app.io.taxiapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
>   10-06 18:54:18.529 17583-18349/com.app.io.taxiapp W/System.err:     ... 21 more
>   10-06 18:54:18.539 17583-17708/com.app.io.taxiapp D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xeeafa60c
>   10-06 18:54:18.539 17583-17708/com.app.io.taxiapp D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xeeafa66c
>   10-06 18:54:18.549 17583-17583/com.app.io.taxiapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@7f3946f time:11454827
>   10-06 18:54:18.559 17583-18349/com.app.io.taxiapp E/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.

Comment: can you replace this: `Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());` to `Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result ", e);` and post the whole stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: please check I've edited the question.

Comment: `Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) ` This is the root of your problem I think. Your connection is refused so your `InputStream` `is` is empty/null since `is = httpEntity.getContent();` fails.

Comment: same code is working fine in other devices, but in my device android M the app is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. Actually data compression mode was on in my device which was stopping many apps to consume internet connectivity, google play services was also one of them. That's why I was getting this error connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)